# How can I get rid of the weeds and moss growing between the paver stones in my driveway?

Tags: driveway, weeds

I used the extra strength roundup to kill the weeds.  Now I have brown weeds that are still rooted in the soil between the paver stones in my driveway.  I've been scraping the weeds and moss out with a screw driver but, darn, that's a tedious job.  I'm hesitant to power wash them away because I don't want to disrupt the sand and risk the paver stones coming lose.

If I were laying this driveway from scratch I'd use polymeric sand to prevent the weeds from popping up, but alas, the previous home owner was very shortsighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd seal it with a little cement mixed with sand, about a 1:4 ratio. Choose a dry day, brush in thoroughly, then sprinkle with a very very fine shower of water.

Answer (score 2):

Hosestly the moss might give the driveway a neat look depending on the age and style of the neighborhood. But if it's a newer house it night looks very poor. And well weeds never look good in a driveway. If it were me I would just go ahead with the power washer and blow it all away. Then when your done have at it with the polymeric sand. This will cover over everything and seal it up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before. But i did  the most tedious way. I pulled all the grass and their roots out. They kept growing back within days. But i kept pulling them out just as they were sprouting. It's easier to pull them out at their earliest stage because their roots aren't that strong yet. It requires less energy. Soon, the re-growing became slower and slower and lesser and lesser.Eventually they stopped sprouting. And anytime i see some new young grass just about sprouting again, i'll quickly go pull them out. I've not had that problem again  for years now. I Just keep my eyes open for new sprouting grass.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out from a neighbour, that to stop the weeds completley one should give the driveway a good clean with the gaps cleared out....then fill the gaps with some sand and finally vanish the whole drive including the gaps....

Comment: "Vanish" the whole drive? I suppose if the whole drive had vanished, there'd be nowhere for weeds to grow...